# Not able to hide div if it contains text

Tags: jquery, html

I have two div inside li and two buttons I want to hide button if second_div class div is present or it contains text please help I have tried various solution hasclass not working

```
<li>
<div class="first_div"></div>
<button></button>
<div class="second_div"></div>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
if( jQuery(".second_div").is(':empty') ){
    if(jQuery( this ).hasClass( "second_div" )){
        jQuery(" .button").css("display":"none");
    }
    //jQuery("ul.products li.product .button").css("display":"none");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've tried to target the button with classname. Try this instead:

```
if ($('.second_div').is(':empty')) {
    $('button').css('display', 'none');
}
```